# Understanding Mathematica: How to write fast code?

Tags: performance-tuning

I'm relatively new to Mathematica but have done a few projects using it so I'm quite comfortable with the syntax and the basic functions available. Since I've had programming experience in the past I learned mostly from referring to documentation and googling specific problems etc.

I do however feel that I don't *understand* Mathematica, in particular, I have almost no idea how to make a fast algorithm in Mathematica(normally I just try a few different approaches and see what works best - with sometimes quite confusing results(in my last project calling fit["MeanPredictionBands"] took appallingly long while it didn't in the past).

So basically I'm looking for a resource that explains the finer workings of Mathematica so that I can write faster code.

I'm aware of one such resource http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/12/07/10-tips-for-writing-fast-mathematica-code/ , while it has some cool tips, I want to know more! :D

Comment: fyi, This is useful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users "what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users"

Comment: Unfortunately I find that this is one of the more difficult to learn parts of Mathematica.  It can be quite difficult to predict performance, and understand what is fast and what is slow.  The duplicate has long answers about this, but even the most experienced users get surprised from time to time about how a piece of code performs.